# Change the type of my output java/ Sparql

Tags: java, sparql

I'm using Java and Sparql to query and to update my ontology.
My question is how can I change the type the output of my query,
I use this method to insert data :

```
Resource createAgent(String prefix, String localName) throws 
AlreadyExistingRdfResourceException {
    String agent = createUri(prefix, localName);
    checkIfExistEntity(agent);
    String create_Agent = "INSERT DATA" +
            "{ <" + agent + ">   rdf:type ac:agent " + " }";

    queryUpdateExec(create_Agent);
    return null;
}
```

And I need to return my agent, but the data type of agent is a `string` and I need to return a `Resource` type.
I tried to use following select query to select my Agent.

```
Resource resultSetq = execSelectAndPrintquery(get_agent).nextSolution().get("? entity").asResource();
```

but it doesn't work as the Sparql returning nothing .. 
Can I get some help please.

Comment: It's totally unclear what your are asking for! You want to change the type of what? An INSERT query does **not** return anything, thus, how do you think you can get a bound variable out of it? It's quite obvious that you have to execute a SELECT query

Comment: And if you want to return an object of Java type `Resource`, you have to use the same URI, you called it `agent` and do `ResourceFactory.createURI(agent)`

Comment: AKSW  hanks for your answer :) this exactly what i need ..